# JavaFX Application unresponsive after drawing multiple canvas

Tags: java, javafx, canvas

I have an application where I want to show a `FlowPane` with PDF pages thumbnails drawn into canvases. I'm using [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) and [FXGraphics2D](https://www.jfree.org/fxgraphics2d/) to render pages.
My current implementation creates a number of canvases as the number of pages, adds them to the `FlowPane` and then spins a number or async tasks to draw the pages content into the canvas.

I'm not sure if the async drawing is the recommended way but the idea is to not use the JavaFX thread to do the PDF parsing to avoid freezing the application.
Now, my issue is this, I can see from the logs that all the rendering tasks have finished and the document is closed. The UI shows some rendered pages but it stays unresponsive for ~10 seconds. After that the application revives, all pages are rendered and everything works nicely.

I tried to profile and I think this is the relevant part:
[image: profiler]
But I have limited knowledge of what is going on under the hood and I couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Do you have an idea or hint on what is wrong with my approach/code and how it can be improved? Ideally I'd like to have the application fast and responsive while the pages thumbnails are filled.

I'm on Linux with a pretty decent machine but I also tested on Windows and got the same behavior. I also tried to replace `FlowPane` with `HBox` or `VBox` but still the same happened.

Here is some ugly code to reproduce the behavior:

```
public class TestApp extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(TestApp.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

            var flow = new FlowPane();
            flow.setOnDragOver(e -> {
                if (e.getDragboard().hasFiles()) {
                    e.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
                }
                e.consume();
            });

            flow.setOnDragDropped(e -> {
                var tasks = new ArrayList<TestApp.RenderTask>();
                try {
                    var document = PDDocument.load(e.getDragboard()
                                                    .getFiles().get(0));
                    var renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
                    for (int i = 1; i <= document.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                        var page = document.getPage(i - 1);
                        var cropbox = page.getCropBox();
                        var thumbnailDimension = new Dimension2D(400,
                                                                 400 * (cropbox.getHeight() / cropbox.getWidth()));
                        var thumbnail = new Canvas(thumbnailDimension.getWidth(), thumbnailDimension.getHeight());
                        var gs = thumbnail.getGraphicsContext2D();
                        var pop = gs.getFill();
                        gs.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                        gs.fillRect(0, 0, thumbnailDimension.getWidth(), thumbnailDimension.getHeight());
                        gs.setFill(pop);

                        tasks.add(new TestApp.RenderTask(renderer, thumbnail, i));
                        flow.getChildren().add(new Group(thumbnail));
                    }

                    var exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
                    tasks.forEach(exec::submit);
                    exec.submit(()-> {
                        try {
                            document.close();
                            System.out.println("close");
                        } catch (IOException ioException) {
                            ioException.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception ioException) {
                    ioException.printStackTrace();
                }

                e.setDropCompleted(true);
                e.consume();
            });
            var scroll = new ScrollPane(flow);
            scroll.setFitToHeight(true);
            scroll.setFitToWidth(true);
            root.setCenter(scroll);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static record RenderTask(PDFRenderer renderer, Canvas canvas, int page) implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            var gs = new FXGraphics2D(canvas.getGraphicsContext2D());
            gs.setBackground(WHITE);
            try {
                renderer.renderPageToGraphics(page - 1, gs);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            gs.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

And [this](http://open-advice.org/Open-Advice.pdf) is the 310 pages PDF file I'm using to test it.
Thanks

Comment: This is just a guess at this point, but I think you're doing too much in one event handler: creating 310 canvas while exploring the pdf to size each one and fill it with white takes time, and meanwhile your `FxApplicationThread` is busy and can't handle other messages. You should do the pre-rendering in a `javafx.concurrent.Service` and use `Platform.runLater` to append each canvas to the `FlowPane`, or append them all at once when it's done (`Service.succeeded`), then launch the rendering

Comment: It doesn't seem to solve anything. I didn't use the `javafx.concurrent.Service` but I got your point and I changed the handler to add the 310 white canvases and this part is super fast and the application is responsive, no issue at all, then I click a button to manually trigger the render tasks and it goes as I described before, nothing changed

Comment: Sorry, I honestly don't see anything wrong with the rest. I have done the same as you once, but using a `javafx.concurrent.Service` to render, and `ImageView` to show the pages, setting each ImageView's image in a `Platform.runLater`. It runs fine for fairly big files. I've not pushed it as far as you did though, as it tended to crash with a OOME when there were too many pages with too high a zoom level

Comment: Yes, that was why I explored the `Canvas` implementation. With `ImageView`s it was working ok with small files  but with big files it was using a lot of memory, a 10x what it's using now with `Canvas` and in the end, once the `FlowPane` was populated, the application wasn't responsive... not stuck but barely usable

Comment: you __must not__ modify a node in an active scenegraph off the fx application thread. Which you seem to do: you first add the canvas to the scenegraph, then pass it off to your renderer thread to be filled with the graphics. Change that to create the canvas (on whatever thread), fill it in the background and when ready pass it back to the ui thread for insertion into the scenegraph.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get what I wanted, the application responds, the thumbnails are populated as they are ready and the memory usage is limited.

**The issue**
I thought I was drawing the canvases off of the FX thread but how `Canvas` works is that you fill a buffer of drawing instructions and they are executed when the canvas becomes part of the scene (I think). What was happening is that I was quickly filling the canvases with a lot of drawing instructions, adding all the canvases to the `FlowPane` and the the application was spending a lot of time actually executing the drawing instructions for 310 canvas and becoming unresponsive for ~10 seconds.

After some reading and suggestions from the JavaFX community here and on Twitter, I tried to switch to an `ImageView` implementation, telling PDFBox to create a `BufferedImage` of the page and use it to create an `ImageView`. It worked nicely but memory usage was 10 times compared to the Canvas impl:
[image: ImageView memory usage]

**The best of both worlds**
In my final solution I add white canvases to the FlowPane, create a `BufferedImage` of the page and convert it to an `Image` off of the FX thread, draw the image to the `Canvas` and discard the `Image`.
This is memory usage for the same 310 pages PDF file:
[image: Canvas memory usage]

And this is the application responsiveness:
[image]

**EDIT (added code to reproduce)**
Here the code I used (with SAMBox instead of PDFBox)

```
public class TestAppCanvasImageMixed extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(TestAppCanvas.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

            var button = new Button("render");
            button.setDisable(true);
            root.setTop(new HBox(button));
            var flow = new FlowPane();
            flow.setOnDragOver(e -> {
                if (e.getDragboard().hasFiles()) {
                    e.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
                }
                e.consume();
            });

            flow.setOnDragDropped(e -> {
                ArrayList<TestAppCanvasImageMixed.RenderTaskToImage> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
                try {
                    var document = PDDocument.load(e.getDragboard()
                                                    .getFiles().get(0));
                    var renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
                    for (int i = 1; i <= document.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                        var page = document.getPage(i - 1);
                        var cropbox = page.getCropBox();
                        var thumbnailDimension = new Dimension2D(400,
                                                                 400 * (cropbox.getHeight() / cropbox.getWidth()));
                        var thumbnail = new Canvas(thumbnailDimension.getWidth(), thumbnailDimension.getHeight());
                        var gs = thumbnail.getGraphicsContext2D();
                        var clip = new Rectangle(thumbnailDimension.getWidth(), thumbnailDimension.getHeight());
                        clip.setArcHeight(15);
                        clip.setArcWidth(15);
                        thumbnail.setClip(clip);
                        var pop = gs.getFill();
                        gs.setFill(WHITE);
                        gs.fillRect(0, 0, thumbnailDimension.getWidth(), thumbnailDimension.getHeight());
                        gs.setFill(pop);
                        var g = new Group();
                        tasks.add(new TestAppCanvasImageMixed.RenderTaskToImage(renderer, 400 / cropbox.getWidth(), i, thumbnail,
                                                                                () -> g.getChildren().setAll(thumbnail)));
                        flow.getChildren().add(new Group());
                    }

                    button.setOnAction(a -> {
                        var exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
                        tasks.forEach(exec::submit);
                        exec.submit(() -> {
                            try {
                                document.close();
                                System.out.println("close");
                            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                                ioException.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    button.setDisable(false);

                } catch (Exception ioException) {
                    ioException.printStackTrace();
                }

                e.setDropCompleted(true);
                e.consume();
            });
            var scroll = new ScrollPane(new StackPane(flow));
           scroll.setFitToHeight(true);
           scroll.setFitToWidth(true);
            root.setCenter(scroll);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static record RenderTaskToImage(PDFRenderer renderer, float scale, int page, Canvas canvas, Runnable r) implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                var bufferedImage = renderer.renderImage(page - 1, scale, ImageType.ARGB, RenderDestination.VIEW);
                var image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null);
                var gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
                gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
                Platform.runLater(() -> r.run());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: would be nice if you post your solution as [mcve] :)